# Inserting CSV data into postgresql table without model - Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv

I have a form which will be uploading a CSV file with table name. Using this table name i have to create a table in Postgresql and then i have move the data in CSV to that table.

As i understood Ruby on Rails works with model(related to a table) to write data. But when i create a table dynamically i should also create a model. But I Have searched on internet for the solution but no success.

So Can i insert the data into the temporary table without model?

Thanks in advance.